# How to show the minimal polynomial of primitive n-th root of unity on prime field with characteristic p is the following?

Tags: finite-fields, primitive-roots

How to show : w, the primitive n-th root of unity over prime field F with characteristic p, gcd(n,p)=1, is $(x-w)(x-w^p)(x-w^{p^2})...(x-w^{p^{r-1}})$ where r is the smallest positive integer s.t. $p^r=1\pmod n$

I know that the minimal polynomial of the primitive n-th root of unity must have order r, which is the smallest positive integer s.t. $p^r=1\pmod n$. But how to show that it exactly factors into the above? I also know that $w^{p^i}$ always have the same minimal polynomial as $w$ for the Frobenius Isomorphism, what I can't show is that : how to show $w^{p^i}$ is necessarily different for each $i\in[0, r-1]$ ?

Comment: Do you know Galois theory?

Comment: @KConrad yes, this claim is from a book about Galois theory.

Comment: See Theorems 3.4 and 4.1 at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/finitefields.pdf.

Comment: Thanks , the book I read doesn't have the proof, it troubled me for days, thanks again!

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @KConrad it's not written in english. I understand the proof now, previously I didn't work out the trick ...

Comment: I am still curious to know what the book is.

Comment: Let $f$ be your polynomial. Because $w$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, $w^k = 1$ iff $k \equiv1$ mod $n$. This established that all the roots of $f$ are distinct. Because the roots of $f$ are permuted by the Frobenius $f$ is in $F_p[x]$. And the minimal polynomial of $w$ must be satisfied by $w^{p^k}$ for each $k >0$, since the Frobenius fixes the base field. This establishes that $f$ is minimal.

Comment: @KConrad it's <伽罗瓦理论>, written in chinese.

Comment: @Bma, I don't think your proof is correct, you need the trick in the above pdf to prove that.

Comment: @mathfan I’m not sure it is. The first point on congruences is correct, the fact that the roots of $f$ are the orbit of $w$ via the Frobenius shows that the coefficients of $f$ are in $F_p$ (since $x^p - x$ has exactly $p$ roots), and the Frobenius is in the Galois group because it fixes the base field (and obviously maps the splitting field to itself), so all elements of the orbit of $w$ under the Frobenius must satisfy the minimal polynomial. Nevertheless  it doesn’t matter much— I’m glad you found your answer.

Comment: @Bma I understand what you mean: because Aut(Fp(w)/Fp) is cyclic group generated by frobenius automorphism of length r, and any other zero of minimal polynomial of w has to be generated by one of Aut(Fp(w)/Fp), thus there're at most r possibilities. But you didn't prove the roots of minimal polynomial of w are different, which is the most important thing of my question. You only said "This established that all the roots of  are distinct" without proof, that each other root is different from w is obvious, what is not so obvious is that each other root is different from each other.

Comment: @mathfan That follows via algebra from the observation that $w^k = 1$ iff $k \equiv 0$ mod $n$ (the same holds with $w$ replaced by another primitive $n$th root). I am not sure if this is done the same way in the notes linked above, as I did not read them in detail. But suppose $w^{p^j} = w^{p^k}$ for $0 \le j < k < r$. Then $1 = w^{p^k - p^j} = w^{p^j(p^{k-j} - 1)}$. Letting $v = w^{p^j}$, $v$ is also a primitive $n$th root of unity because $p$ and $n$ are coprime. But $0 < k-j < r$, so by assumption on $r$, $p^{k-j}$ is not congruent to 1 mod $n$, and therefore $v^{p^{k-j} - 1}$ cannot be 1.

Comment: I see now that I mistakenly wrote $w^k = 1$ iff $k \equiv 1$ mod $n$ in my first comment. I should have written that $w^k = 1$ iff $k \equiv 0$ mod $n$. My apologies.

Comment: Yeah the argument of $v^{p^{k-j}-1}$ can not be 1 is the main thing of my question:)